# Convert integer to hex in Python

Tags: python, integer, hex

In Python I want to tranform the integer `3892` into a hexcode with the given format and the result `\x00\x00\x0F\x34`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What if the integer is more than 32-bits?

Comment: Hmmm, so you want code based on a hope and prayer, fine. When you say "hexcode with the given format" do you mean literally a string of bytes representing the 32-bit value `0x0f34` on a big-endian machine, or do you mean literally the character string `"\\x00\\x00\\x0F\\x34"`?

Comment: In other words, do you need a 16 character string (textual representation) or 4 bytes (binary representation)?

Answer (score 8):

You are converting to a binary representation of the number, not so much a hex representation (although Python will display the bytes as hex). Use the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) for such conversions.

Demonstration:

```
>>> struct.pack('>I', 3892)
'\x00\x00\x0f4'
>>> struct.pack('>I', 4314)
'\x00\x00\x10\xda'
```

Note that the ASCII code for '4' is 0x34, python only displays bytes with a `\x` escape if it is a non-printable character. Because 0x34 is printable, python outputs that as `4` instead.

'>' in the formatting code above means 'big endian' and 'I' is an unsigned int conversion (4 bytes).

Comment: Isn't 3892 decimal 0xf34 hexadecimal?

Comment: @martineau: I address that in my answer; python displays '4' because that is the ASCII character at code position 0x34. Thus, the last character in the byte sequence is `\x34` but because it is printable it is not displayed as a hex escape.

Comment: Ahhh, I get what you meant by the statement in your answer now, thanks. It's unclear if the OP wants this or what @cdarke's answer produces, but suspect it's probably the former, so will have to add my own +1.

Comment: Updated with a second, independent example that does produce 4 unprintable bytes.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
print re.sub(r'([0-9A-F]{2})',r'\\x\1','%08X' % 3892)
```

gives:

```
\x00\x00\x0F\x34
```

Comment: wow! thats it - really cool. Thanks a lot.
@cdarke for the sake of my mediocre regex-skills: could you give me a short explenation of your regex?

Comment: This produces a 16-character string with literal backslash, literal `x` and literal digits. `'%08X'` produces the hexadecimal digits, and the regular expression inserts a literal `\x` every two digits. My solution produces *4* bytes, which contain your number as an unsigned [C long value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Common_long_integer_sizes). You need to figure out what format you need to write to your file; if it is a binary format my bet is on my answer. :-)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have been travelling.  The RE is as follows (in addition to @Martijn Pieters correct explaination): `([0-9A-F]{2})` looks for exactly 2 hexadecimal digits.  The parentheses () capture what we matched, and are represented in the replacement string as `\1` (called a back-reference).  `\\x` prefixes the captured two characters with `\x`.   Would be nice if you accepted my solution if you are happy with it, but I agree with others that your question is a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

If you have numpy installed:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.int32(3892).tostring()
'4\x0f\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers! But I need as actual result the \x00\x00\x0F\x34 as I have to import it back into a file. Is it possible to do this?