# How to convert int to little endian hex with "\x" prefix?

Tags: python, hex

I want to convert a decimal integer into a `\xLO\xHI` hex string while keeping the "\x" prefix and without translating printable ASCII to their equivalent ASCII.

What I want to achieve:

```
>>> dec_to_hex(512)
"\x00\x02"
```

---

**The following solutions I found while searching for an answer aren't good enough and I'll explain why:**

*This one didn't put the "\x"  prefix and don't translated it to bytes*

```
>>> hex(512)
'0x200'
```

*This examples is really close but receives hexadecimal (I need decimal) and translated chars to ascii:*

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> unhexlify('65004100430005FF70000000')
'e\x00A\x00C\x00\x05\xffp\x00\x00\x00'
```

*This one translates ASCIIinto chars:*

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('<h', 512)
'\x00\x02'
>>> struct.pack('<h', 97)
'a\x00'
```

Comment: Have you tried the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683294/convert-integer-to-hex-in-python) thread?
Regarding little endian you can use '<I' instead of '>I' which will be big endian.

Comment: `struct` translates ascii into characters (97 to 'a', 103 to 'g' etc).

Comment: The other answer is close, `print re.sub(r'([0-9A-F]{2})',r'\\x\1','%04X' % 512)` but isn't a little endian

Comment: Have you tried the repr() function?
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990060/python-struct-pack-behavior) thread how to use it.

Example code:
`repr(struct.pack('<h', 97)).strip("'")`

Comment: it translates 97 to "a" as well